# Having trouble finding the matrix that satisfies the equation

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that ($E_3$ is a elementary matrix) $E_3 \begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&5\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}19&32\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$ Find $E_3^{-1}$ and $E_3$

So I am trying to find $E_3$ but this time it seems to be a bit more difficult because now I am solving for a $2 \times 2$ instead of a single vector.

So I attempted this and got: (setting $b=0, c=0$ since it is a elem. matrix..)

$12a_1 + 35b = 19 \implies a_1 = 19/12$

$12a_2 + 35b = 32 \implies a_2 = 8/3$

$12c_1 + 35d = 3 \implies d_1 = 35/3$

$12c_2 + 35d = 5 \implies d_2 = 1/7$

I'm not sure now how I can get $E_1$ becase I know for $E_1$ I will have $b= 0, c = 0$

So should I add the two a equations together or the d's? I'm not really sure how to get $a$ and $d$

**EXTRA:** (Here is an image of the question in case i am interpreting it wrong, also my teacher said to assume they are elem matrix)

Apparently the answer is $E_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1&6\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ I have no idea how
[image]

Comment: How can a product of a $2\times 2$ matrix and a $2\times1$ matrix be a $2\times2$ matrix?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense: For $E_3$ to be invertible, it must be square. For the first equation to make sense, it must be $2 \times 2$, which makes the first equation *not* make sense.

Comment: That is exactly the question and how I am given it. I'll even post a image if you don't believe me.

Comment: @T.Bongers I'm not really sure, but this is the question I'm given. Any other ideas?

Comment: Apparently the answer is $E_3 = \begin{bmatrix}1&6\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ I have no idea how

Comment: The vector is a matrix, just spaced badly in the problem description.

Comment: Is that first matrix a $12$ and a $35$, or is it $1$, $2$, $3$, and $5$?

Comment: @Jed 12 and 35.

Comment: @Aweygan Wow, you're saying thats 1932 and 35. How horrible!

Comment: @Aweygan I was like what!! lol

Comment: But based on how close the $19$ and $32$ are in the second matrix, it seems possible that the spacing is just very small.  Also, since it is not mathematically possible for it to be $12$ and $35$, I think perhaps it is not.

Comment: @Shammy its $\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\3&5\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: @Aweygan I don't think so. Did you work it out and get (1,0) and (6,1) ?

Comment: If you do the matrix multiplication with the matrix you gave as the answer, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 6 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 19 & 32 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ does hold true. It must be $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Can someone show me how to set up this system of equations? I'm getting $a + 3b = 19 \implies a = 9$ and $c + 3d = 32 \implies d = 32/3$ which is obviously incorrect

Comment: An elementary matrix can have non-zero off-diagonal entries.

Comment: @T.Bongers How can I setup the equations so I can find the first entry; $1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1:

Ignoring the fact that $E_3$ is an elementary matrix, you can just compute

$$E_3 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 19 & 32 \\ 3 & 5\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5\end{array}\right]^{-1}$$

There is an explicit formula for the inverse of a $2 \times 2$ matrix, or you can just do a standard process like row-reduction.

---

Solution 2:

Writing $$E_3 = \left[\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right]$$
write a system of four equations in four variables, the first of which could be
$$a + 3c = 19$$

Now execute whatever your favorite algorithm for solving this system.

---

Solution 3:

There are very few elementary matrices. After approximately two minutes of trial and error, you should be looking for one of the form
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & ? \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: In solution 1; are we able to do this because $x = A^{-1}b$?

Comment: What are $x, A$, and $b$, and what do they have to do with this, @Shammy? This is just matrix algebra, rearranging things by moving inverses around.

Comment: This makes sense. The shortcut I think says $\begin{bmatrix}-d&b\\c&-a\end{bmatrix}$ thank you

Comment: @Shammy Your signs are off, and you're missing a term $ad - bc$.